# Sending different kill signals to init - how to log

Tags: log, c, init, kill

I have to write a C program to check how init reacts to different kill signals, however I am not sure how to log it - for example signal number 14 crashes the ubuntu, then some higher one turns it off. Is there any way to log it properly so that I know how does system react to each signal? Here is the C code I use, any feedback on that would be also appreciated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int sigs[64] = { 0 };
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) sigs[i] = i+1;
    char sigs_char[64][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++) sprintf(sigs_char[i], "%d", sigs[i]);

    char one[2] = " 1";

    char commands[64][128];
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        strcpy(commands[i], "sudo kill -s ");
        strncat(commands[i], sigs_char[i], 2);
        strcat(commands[i], one);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++){
        printf("Sending signal number %d\n", i);
        system(commands[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why such a roundabout way and not [`kill(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/kill.2.html)?

Comment: I am new to linux, had no idea about that command. I assume just sudo kill(1, <1 to 64>)) ? But anyway, I am more interested in how to log how the init reacts to it.

Comment: Yes, something like: `for(i=0;i<64;i++) { kill (1, i); }`. The question is what do you mean, how `init` reacts? If it crashes, you get a kernel panic and you won't be able to do anything. You cannot deliver killing signals (see documentation of `kill(2)`, or [this SO question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7441/70524)). That leaves signals which cause `init` to reload or voluntarily shutdown, both of which should leave traces in `/var/log/syslog`, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no general way to "log" `init`'s reaction. First, there's the fact that `kill` won't deliver any signals to `init` that `init` isn't handling (from [`man 2 kill`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/kill.2.html)):

```
NOTES
       The only signals that can be sent to process ID 1,  the  init  process,
       are  those  for  which  init  has explicitly installed signal handlers.
       This is done to assure the system is not brought down accidentally.
```

So, for many signals, there won't be a reaction at all. Now that leaves the signals that *are* handled. Using [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to), we can determine those<sup>1</sup>:

```
$ HANDLED_SIGS=$(awk '/SigCgt/{print "0x"$2}' /proc/1/status)
$ for i in {0..31}; do (( (1 << i) & $HANDLED_SIGS )) && echo $((++i)) $(/bin/kill --list=$i); done | column
1 HUP   6 ABRT  11 SEGV 15 TERM 30 PWR
2 INT   10 USR1 14 ALRM 17 CHLD 32
```

Of these:

- `SIGABRT` and `SIGSEGV` caused core dumps and kernel panics. Nothing to be detected here.
- `SIGTERM` caused it to reload, with log messages in `/var/log/syslog`:

  ```
  Nov 14 00:25:13 vm kernel: [32383.384907] init: upstart-udev-bridge main process (395) terminated with status 1
  Nov 14 00:25:13 vm kernel: [32383.384916] init: upstart-udev-bridge main process ended, respawning
  Nov 14 00:25:13 vm kernel: [32383.384990] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process (649) terminated with status 1
  Nov 14 00:25:13 vm kernel: [32383.384995] init: upstart-socket-bridge main process ended, respawning
  Nov 14 00:25:13 vm kernel: [32383.385059] init: upstart-file-bridge main process (953) terminated with status 1
  Nov 14 00:25:13 vm kernel: [32383.385074] init: upstart-file-bridge main process ended, respawning
  ```
- `SIGINT` caused it to start a reboot, and `SIGPWR` started a shutdown. Both looked like normal ones (say, like if you did a `reboot`, for example).
- None of the others caused any visible effects. (Though, considering `init`'s duties, we can guess what `SIGCHLD` does.)

And all this is for Upstart. Who knows how SysV or systemd will react?

So, all in all, you're not going to have much luck with empirical methods here. [*Use the Source, Luke.*](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~upstart-devel/upstart/trunk/files)

---

<sup>1</sup>That convoluted bit of code is for getting the signals that `init` is willing to catch:

```
HANDLED_SIGS=$(awk '/SigCgt/{print "0x"$2}' /proc/1/status)
for i in {0..31} 
do 
    (( (1 << i) & $HANDLED_SIGS )) && echo $((++i)) $(/bin/kill --list=$i); 
done | column
```

- `HANDLED_SIGS=$(awk '/SigCgt/{print "0x"$2}' /proc/1/status)`: `/proc/$PID/status` contains a wealth of information about the process, including [the set of handled signals](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85364/how-can-i-check-what-signals-a-process-is-listening-to). This set is given by `SigCgt`, a bitmask given as a hexadecimal number. We use `awk` to extract that number and add `0x` as a prefix.
- `(( (1 << i) & $HANDLED_SIGS ))`: check if signal no. `(i+1)` is masked. Since we're concerned about the `i`th bit, we use 2<sup>(i-1)</sup> (which is `1 << i`). With `(( ))`, a non-zero value indicates success.